# mongodb "update" + "$or" combination doesn't work as expected

Tags: mongodb

I was running following script to update data with $or operator.

```
db.getCollection('test').update( 
    {$or: [{c1:true, c2: true  }] } ,
    {$set: {rs:  true }},
    {multi:true}
)
```

It was expected that all following rows should be updated, but only row 3 & 4 were, as $or worked as $and.

/* 1 */
{
    "c1" : true
}

/* 2 */
{
    "c2" : true
}

/* 3 */
{
    "c1" : true,
    "c2" : true
}

/* 4 */
{
    "c1" : true,
    "c2" : true
}

Here is the screenshot:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Qhn.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) query operator takes an array of query expression objects, but you're passing both terms in a single object, making it behave as an AND.

Instead, put each `$or` term in its own object in the array like this:

```js
db.getCollection('test').update( 
    {$or: [{c1:true}, {c2: true}]},
    {$set: {rs: true}},
    {multi:true}
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that works! I am new to mongodb and am getting used to nosql style query.